# Easiest way how to plot plenty side by side graphs using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say we want to plot 12 graphs side-by-side using ggplot. For instance

```
qplot(x,3*x+eps) #I want to have 12 graphs of this 
plot_grid()      #And now I can insert 12 times qplot above into plot_grid to get my result.
```

My question is : is there any way how can I plot it without putting qplot to plot_grid 12 times ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `replicate` to repeat the plots and `do.call` to plot them using `plot_grid` :

```
do.call(cowplot::plot_grid, replicate(12, qplot(x,3*x+eps), simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: Yea, this would work for sure, thanks ;)) what if I would have 12 different plots ? ;))

Comment: Are those 12 different plots stored somewhere? In a list, maybe? You can use `do.call(cowplot::plot_grid, list_of_12_plots)`.

Comment: The problem is that if we would use code with list for example (two plots)

plot_grid(as.list(qplot(x,3*x+eps),qplot(x,2*x+eps)))

it would plot only the first graph

Comment: No, you are using it incorrectly. For 2 graphs, here are the options - 1) `plot_grid(qplot(x,3*x+eps), qplot(x,2*x+eps))` 2) `do.call(plot_grid, list(qplot(x,3*x+eps), qplot(x,2*x+eps)))` 3) `do.call(plot_grid, lapply(2:3, function(y) qplot(x,y*x+eps)))` . I am not sure which one of this is applicable/better suited for your case.